# Passing values from another activity to out of onCreate

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to create a board game and want to pass the number of the board size form another activity.

```
    val colRow =return intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_COLROW,0)

    private val boardCells = Array(colRow) { arrayOfNulls<Button>(colRow) }

    var board = Board(colRow)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        }
```

the error message below showed up

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Intent.getIntExtra(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference

I tried to put the intent code in function but it doesn't work as well

```
    val colRow =getColrow()

    fun getColrow():Int{
        return intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_COLROW,0)
    }
```

Does the intent getExtra only work in onCreate method? If it so how can I pass the values to out side of the oncreate?
Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Save the extra value to a variable

```
private lateinit val colRow: Int
private lateinit val boardCells: Array
private lateinit val board: Board

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
     colRow = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_COLROW,0)
     initBoard()
}

private fun initBoard(){
     boardCells = Array(colRow) { arrayOfNulls<Button>(colRow) }
     board = Board(colRow)
}
```

use it anywhere within that activity.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, but  sorry the code didn't work. There was a suggestion and it changed as
 " private lateinit val colRow: Int" => "private var colRow by Delegates.notNull<Int>()"
but it still doesn't work  shows same error message.

Comment: you are using this line `colRow = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_COLROW,0)`  inside `onCreate`  method right?

Comment: Yes. also  It was appeared in "private lateinit var boardCells: Array"  the Array needs <T>

Answer (score 0):

try to use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) framwork

simplifies the communication between components

decouples event senders and receivers

performs well with Activities, Fragments, and background threads

avoids complex and error-prone dependencies and life cycle issues

makes your code simpler

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But sorry I'm just a beginner I don'T understand how to use it in Android Studio. I'll try it later